# how to debug memory overwrite in scale setup

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb, heap-memory

I have got a segmentation fault where instead of a memory address , there is some other value copied and when that address is dereferenced that coredump happens.I did a code walkthrough and nothing seems incorrect and in normal scenario it is not hit.This is a scale setup. This is a corner case and not consistent issue.

I checked raw memory dump and this looks a valid heap address for address the variable which is saving this and value is also a valid value.

Is there any options/tools you can suggest to debug this? efence or valgrind can be useful in this case ? any other tool or in gdb we can do something?Reproduction is also difficult.

for more clarity, for example, we have datapoint which should store address of some variable and size of that, the variable is of type datapoint is storing both values from NODE.

```
typedef struct node{
 uint32 valueA;
 uint8 valueB;
}NODE;
typedef struct datapoint{
     void* address;
     unsigned size;
}DP;
```

Comment: Running a build compiled with `-fsanitize=address` can help

Comment: What Kind of addresses are you talking about? The code does not contain any pointers

Comment: @Gerhardh , sorry, I will add the corrections , uint32 address; is void* ptr.

Comment: The `valgrind` tool can also be helpful in diagnosing memory use problems.

Comment: You should show a bit more of your code. On nowadays PCs, a `void*` has a different size than a `uint32_t`. A 32 bit integer cannot hold an address on a modern 64 bit system. How do you map the value in these 2 structs? How do you acces them? How do you dereference your pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Here Problem was we had an array of dp type , so say we have some 5 members allowed in that array and next to it was node variable, in add method we were not restricting and allowing 6th member to be added and that was overwriting NODE and when we try to access node it was causing core as it has values of DP type.

```
struct problem_struct{
   DP array[5];
   NODE another_value;
}
```